# On passing argument to a callback function

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

I have some ambiguity in Javascript callback functions.

The first code is structured as follows:

```
function firstFunction()
{
 var message = "something";
 secondFunction(message);
}

function secondFunction(message)
{
   var myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");
   myButton.addEventListener('click',thirdFunction(message));
}

function thirdFunction(message)
{
 console.log("the messages is: "+message);
}
```

When I run the script above, the `thirdFunction` gets executed without clicking the button.

After some research, I read about the `closure` in Javascript. Then I changed the code to the following structure:

```
function firstFunction()
{
 var message = "something";
 secondFunction(message);
}

function secondFunction(message)
{
   var myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");
   myButton.addEventListener('click',thirdFunction);
}

function thirdFunction(message)
{
  return function(){
  console.log("the messages is: "+message);
  }
}
```

I got the expected result. The `thirdFunction` is executed only when the button is clicked.

I am not sure if I my second code structure is correct? I am not sure if I'm getting the closure concept correctly as I never returned a function in conventional programming before. This is a new concept to me. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

**EDIT:**
Some of the solutions suggest writing it like this:

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', function() { thirdFunction(message) });
```

For code readability, I am trying to avoid this. I prefer to place the code for the `thirdFunction` outside the `secondFunction`.

Comment: Has nothing to do with callbacks, it has to do with binding Event Listener

Comment: Your second code would work if you do `myButton.addEventListener('click',thirdFunction(message));` - but defining such closures inline is more readable. Your first code works if you replace `thirdFunction(message)` with `() => thirdFunction(message)` - which I would prefer.

Comment: But it worked as I posted it without passing `message`.

Comment: @user6875880 You either need to pass `message` or you have a global `message` variable declaration somewhere. Regarding "I prefer to place the code for the thirdFunction outside the secondFunction." - well, that's exactly what it is doing. Encapsulating the call to `thirdFunction` within an inline function expression is a common technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function to make the closure in the correct environment:

```
function secondFunction(message)
{
   var myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");
   myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     thirdFunction(message)
   });
}
```